# If I have edit privileges, how do I suggest an edit?

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits, privileges

I have 2000 rep points and therefore have edit privileges, but I want to suggest an edit to an answer, because I wouldn't just improve grammar and formatting, but overhaul the answer to make it more clear and concise. I think the poster would appreciate it, but I want to get their permission first.

Possible solutions:

- Use a private browsing session to suggest the edit as an anonymous user
- Go ahead and post it (and let OP roll it back if they prefer)
- Write a comment asking if OP would appreciate it

Comment: You can drop the edited version in a gist, then leave a comment on the answer asking the user to decide if they want to use it.

Comment: @Won't That would work perfectly. You should submit that as an answer on the duplicate question.